# How can I fix my python script to inject a DLL?

Tags: python, x86-64, dll-injection

I am new to DLL injection and I am trying to learn how to do it. I found a DLL injector source code from http://www.mpgh.net/forum/showthread.php?t=209479. I tried to translate the code from C to python:

```
from ctypes import *

def dllinjector(processID, DLL_NAME):
    PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x0002
    PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400
    PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008
    PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020
    PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010
    openHandle = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD|
                                             PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|
                                             PROCESS_VM_OPERATION|
                                             PROCESS_VM_WRITE|
                                             PROCESS_VM_READ, False, processID)
    MEM_RESERVE = 0x00002000
    MEM_COMMIT = 0x00001000
    PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04

    if not openHandle:
        print("OpenProcess failed.")
        return False

    print("Successfully opened process.")

    LoadLibAddy = windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress(windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA"); 

    # Allocate space in the process for the dll
    RemoteString = windll.kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(openHandle, None, len(DLL_NAME), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)
    if not RemoteString:
        print("VirtualAllocEx failed.")
        return False

    # Write the string name of the dll in the memory allocated
    if not windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(openHandle, RemoteString, DLL_NAME, len(DLL_NAME), None):
        print("WriteProcessMemory failed.")
        print(windll.kernel32.GetLastError())
        return False

    #Load the dll
    #print(windll.kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(openHandle, None, None, LoadLibAddy, RemoteString, None, None))

    windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(openHandle)

    return True

def main():
    processID = 18364
    DLL_NAME = "mydll.dll"

    #mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('mydll.dll')

    dllinjector(processID, DLL_NAME)

    print("program completed.")

main()
```

The problem I am having is when I call WriteProcessMemory it is returning 0. I have read the docs and according to them the function will return 0 if there was an error and it says to use the GetLastError function to get more information. However, when I call GetLastError all that is displayed is 0. Also, when I call windll.kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(openHandle, None, None, LoadLibAddy, RemoteString, None, None) the program that I am trying to inject the dll into (Calc.exe) crashes (I am assuming it is because WriteProcessMemory is not working but I am not sure). I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain to me why WriteProcessMemory is not working.

Comment: I tried switching to a 32-bit application and WriteProcessMemory now works. However CreateRemoteThread still crashes the program.